# PHP PDO lastInsertId returns string instead of integer

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, pdo, identity

I'm currently building a symfony/doctrine app and one model has the following structure:

```
Session:
  columns:
    session_id:
      type: integer(8)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    session_number:
      type: string(30)
```

This correctly maps to the database as:

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `session_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_number` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
```

So we are safe there.

Then when trying to create a new record the code goes:

```
$newSession = new Session();
$newSession->session_number = session_id();
$newSession->save();
//...
echo $newSession->session_id; //<------ this will return a string '1'
```

The last line is the problematic. The session_id field gets filled in with the last identity value but **as a string!!**

So at first, I thought doctrine was the culprit, but then debugging the code, I found out that it seems that PDO is actually the one that is returning the value as a string. The method that gets called is:

```
dbh->lastInsertId()
```

So the obvious question is: **how can I solve this?**. I found these things in the internet but haven't tried them yet:

1. PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES. Will this work? If yes, how can I configure that?
2. Using mysql native driver instead of pdo. However doctrine handles it so I'm not sure if I can even configure that.
3. The other obvious workaround is to typecast to int : (int)$session->session_id. But that's just plain ugly as it should return an integer value (that's the whole purpose of using pdo and doctrine!) and all the other models would have the same issue.
4. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Re #3 - no, it should **not** return an integer - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php. In any case, what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem with having the id as a numeric string, and beware that if you do force it to int, it will break if the id goes out of the integer range for php...

Comment: @therefromher Integers are 10 digits long minimum on 32bits systems, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @MUYBelgium Well aside from it being just plain dumb to create a nasty bug like that, I can certainly see cases where you'd get a row id to go past 31 bits - eg a logging table.  Putting it the other way, what possible reason would you have for requiring the id value be an int rather than a numeric string?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use conversion function [see php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

```
$myInteger = intval($myString)
```

In order to send an exception if the string represents a too high number to be converted into an integer (and avoid some nasty intermittent bugs in your code), please surround with this code :

```
$myInteger = intval($myString)
if ($myInteger === PHP_INT_MAX) { // PHP 4.4.0 & 5.0.5 min
      throw new Exception('Integer out of range, please call your developer for bug fixing!')
}
```